# How do I implement Serializable? For storing my data in Session

Tags: java, tomcat, serializable, notserializableexception, session-replication

Hi I have been trying to do session replication between my 2 tomcat clusters...and also I am maintain sticky session...I am currently having a problem that after adding  tag in web.xml and running my application it gives an error like `**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute**` and when I referred the tomcat documentation for finding solution it was mentioned that **All your session attributes must implement java.io.Serializable**

...and I get doubt here all my session attributes must implement serializable means that all the objects I am storing in the session using setattribute must implement serializable interface...that mean if I am doing

```
public class MySession {
  String sessionObj1 = "Hello";
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
  session.setAttribute("New-Session-1", sessionObj1);
}
```

Here sessionObj1 is a String Object and serializable likewise I should set only objects that implements serializable interface

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense since it looks like a method body but it's just at class level. In general implementing `Serializable` should be sufficient as long as all _fields_ in a class do so too. `String` already implements that interface so if `sessionObj1` were a field that would be ok (of course the other lines wouldn't even compile).

Comment: I just wrote that code as rough code here...to get clarified...I have another small doubt that is how do I make my JSONObject serializable...I am also setting a session object of org.json.JSONObject class here this JSONObject is not serializable...I cannot can't also change this  JSONObject  to string as mentioned in other answer given to this question related to this in stack overflow

Comment: @Thomas and tnx by the way for answer

Comment: Well, since JSONObject isn't serializable you need to take other measures, i.e. either just store the json string, parse the json into a proper pojo that is serializable, or add custom serialization and deserialization code to your session.

Comment: Bro my problem is I am not allowed to modify the session.setAttribute(jsonObj)...so I am un able to set jsonobject to string...is there any other ways that I can use to serialize the json object that is being set at session